# animations in Cocos2dx

Tags: android, ios, animation, cocos2d-x

I am working on an app which has a lot of basic animations like rotation, translation, scaling. I am an objC programmer and don't have any prior experience in cocos or game development environment hence this is coming difficult to me. I have googled a lot for this and found few examples which are repeated all around. can anyone help me with a pseudo code or at least a basic idea to begin with and some accompanying explanation to guide me through.

Comment: A good begin is to differentiate between 'android' and 'ios'. Is your app for just *one* of these platforms, or for both? (Where the latter would mean your 'cocos2d-x' tag is irrelevant.)

Comment: it is for both platforms, iOS and android.

Comment: Apologies, I see cocos2d-x is a cross-platform engine. The iOS-only equivalent is called *cocoa* :)

Answer (score 2):

The below code will move your sprite once:

```
CCSprite *sprite=CCSprite::create("image.png");
CCMoveTo *moveSprite=CCMoveTo::create(0.5, ccp(200, 400));
sprite->runAction(moveSprite);
```

The below line will scale your sprite:

```
sprite->setScale(1.2);
```

The below code will rotate your sprite:

```
CCRotateBy *rotate = CCRotateBy::create(0.8f, 360.0f);
sprite->runAction(CCRepeat::create(rotate, 5));
```

These are the basic animations if you need more do reply.

Comment: this is something close to what I was looking for, thanks aniket. If u could help me with more such solutions; that will be very kind of you.

Comment: What is it that you want?

Answer (score 2):

**Frame Animation in Cocos2dX**

```
CCAnimation *animation = CCAnimation::create();

 // load image file from local file system to CCSpriteFrame, 
 then add into CCAnimation

 for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)

 {
 char szImageFileName[128] = {0};

  sprintf(szImageFileName, "Images/grossini_dance_%02d.png", i);
  animation->addSpriteFrameWithFileName(szImageFileName);  
 }

animation->setDelayPerUnit(2.8f / 14.0f); // This animation contains 14 frames, will     continuous 2.8 seconds.

animation->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true); // Return to the 1st frame after the 14th frame is played. 

CCAnimate *action = CCAnimate::create(animation);

sprite->runAction(action);  // run action on sprite object
```

Answer (score 1):

So there are basically two types of animations you could run on your image (or `ccsprite`).

1: Translations:- `CCmoveBy`,`CCmoveTo`,`CCrotateBy` etc.

2: Frame Animations.

There usage is as follows...

```
CCSprite *sprite=CCSprite::create("image.png");

CCMoveTo *moveSprite=CCMoveTo::create(0.5, ccp(200, 400));
sprite->runAction(moveSprite);
```

and

```
CCAnimation *animation = CCAnimation::create();

 // load image file from local file system to CCSpriteFrame, 
 then add into CCAnimation

 for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)

 {
 char szImageFileName[128] = {0};

  sprintf(szImageFileName, "Images/grossini_dance_%02d.png", i);
  animation->addSpriteFrameWithFileName(szImageFileName);  
 }

animation->setDelayPerUnit(2.8f / 14.0f); // This animation contains 14 frames, will     continuous 2.8 seconds.

CCAnimate *action = CCAnimate::create(animation);

sprite->runAction(action);  // run action on sprite object
```

Or..

```
sprite->runAction(ccRepeatForever::create(action));
```

You should know that moveTo,moveBy or ccRepeatForever they all are subclasses of ccAction

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple animation and some complex animation by using cocos2dx. some third party tools are available for making sprite frame and you can run animation on these frames by using code of cocos2dx.

```
CCSpriteBatchNode* spritebatch = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("horse.png");
CCSpriteFrameCache* cache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("horse.plist");

// "hero" is CCSprite and "horse_1.png" is a sprite in "horse.png" batch node

hero = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("horse_1.png");
addChild(spritebatch);
spritebatch->addChild(hero);

CCLog("In the anim2");

CCArray* animFrames = CCArray::createWithCapacity(16);
char str[100] = {0};
for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
{
    // in my batch node all the sprite name as 'horse_1.png', 'horse_2.png'.....
    sprintf(str, "horse_%i.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = cache->spriteFrameByName( str );
    animFrames->addObject(frame);
}
CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, .1f);
animation->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true);
hero->runAction( CCRepeatForever::create( CCAnimate::create(animation) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Examples/samples you can find are here in Cocos 2dx itself Cocos2dxHome->Samples->Cpp->TestCpp->Classes .

Answer (score 0):

At first you need a software to make a plist file.when you got plist file you can use this code to make a Animation.

```
CCSprite *pBody = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("enemy1_m_1.png");
CC_BREAK_IF(!pBody);

CCSpriteFrameCache* pAttac_FrameCache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
pAttac_FrameCache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("ZombieAttack.plist",CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("ZombieAttack.png"));
CCAnimation *pAttac_Animation = CCAnimation::create();
pAttac_Animation->setDelayPerUnit(0.1f);
pAttac_Animation->setLoops(-1);
int nIndeies = 0;                   //Format Name of Picture index

while(true){
    char szFrameName[_FILE_NAME_LEN_] = {0};
    sprintf(szFrameName,"ZombieAttack_%d.png",nIndeies++);
    CCSpriteFrame* pFrame = pAttac_FrameCache->spriteFrameByName(szFrameName);
    CC_BREAK_IF(pFrame ==NULL);
    pAttac_Animation->addSpriteFrame(pFrame);
}
pBody->runAction(pAttac_Animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can Do like this...........

```
//"horse.png" through which batch node crate

    CCSpriteBatchNode* spritebatch = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("horse.png");
    CCSpriteFrameCache* cache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
    cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("horse.plist");

    // "hero" is CCSprite and "horse_1.png" is a sprite in "horse.png" batch node

   hero = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("horse_1.png");
    addChild(spritebatch);
    spritebatch->addChild(hero);

    CCLog("In the anim2");

    CCArray* animFrames = CCArray::createWithCapacity(16);
    char str[100] = {0};
    for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
        // in my batch node all the sprite name as 'horse_1.png', 'horse_2.png'.....
        sprintf(str, "horse_%i.png", i);
        CCSpriteFrame* frame = cache->spriteFrameByName( str );
        animFrames->addObject(frame);
    }
    CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, .1f);
    animation->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true);
    hero->runAction( CCRepeatForever::create( CCAnimate::create(animation) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to move a sprite left right continuously:

```
CCSprite* mySprite=CCSprite::create("menuBtn.png");
this->addChild(mySprite,1);
CCActionInterval* move=CCMoveBy::create(0.5,ccp(30,0));
mySprite->runAction(CCRepeatForever::create(CCSequence::create(move,move->reverse(),NULL)));
```

CCSequence creates a new action/animation which is a combination of move and move->reverse().

You can use CCRepeatForever to repeat an action infinitely or use CCRepeat which takes number of times as input parameter to its constructor.

CCScaleBy, CCScaleTo, CCRotateBy, CCRotateTo, all these can be used in a similar manner and they can be sequenced using CCSequence.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I've been through when I started learning Cocos2dx, there are two ways to mess around with CCSprite:

1. Update Timer + Instant Action Per Update Call (ScheduleUpdate + CCActionInstant);
2. Action In Finite Time (CCActionInterval)

For 1, the template code should like this:

```
 CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getScheduler()->scheduleSelector(schedule_selector(NewGame::update),this,0.1,false);

 NewGame::update(float dt)
 {
    ...
    //subClass of CCActionInstant
    if(sprite-> isFlipX())
    sprite->runAction(CCFlipX::create(true));
    else
    sprite->runAction(CCFlipX::create(false));
    ...
 }

 This code will make sprite to change orientation per 0.1 sec.
```

For  2, there are many sample codes and all in very similar style:

```
CCActionInterval* actionMoveBy = CCMoveBy::actionWithDuration(1,ccp(-50,-50) );
m_Soldier->runAction(actionMoveTo);
```

Move (-50, -50) in 1 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Your best friend is the test application. Compile it and run it, find something similar to what you want to do and check the code for it. You can find the source in cocos2d-x/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/ ([link to github](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/v3/tests/cpp-tests/Classes))

If you need examples about animations you can check the projects related to actions (ActionManagerTest, ActionEaseTest, etc);

Answer (score 0):

You can use LevelHelper and SpriteHelper . Coding Part is not required for animations .